# How to expand tabs to spaces, but only for visual aid only

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am starting with a new project with a lot of legacy code in C and Golang

The developers there are adamant on using `tab` :P and enforce 80 column limit

I am not a fan of `tabs` and am having hard time trying to adapt.

This is my `.vimrc` content where I had to remove `expandtab` for this project

```
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·

set tabstop=4

set softtabstop=4

set shiftwidth=4

set cc=80
```

The issue I am struggling with is that the build(make) process expands `tab` to 8 column width and complains lines are too long. If I open the files in Vim or VSCode, they appear fine as the tabs are not expanded.

How may I achieve a configuration where pressing `tab` still inserts a `tab`, but visually expands to 8 column width in Vim and VSCode.

**Note:** I don't want to replace tabs with spaces in the files, that battle is already lost. **I just want to do that visually, while coding so that building the code is less frustrating**

Answer (score 0):

It seems it just needs this small change in .vimrc

```
set tabstop=8
```